# Qtablewidget or Qtableview, which is more proper to make a downloading task list?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Qtablewidget or Qtableview, which is more proper to make a downloading task list ?

I want to make a downloading task list like this 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/images/widgetdelegate.png

1. the first question is : Qtablewidget or Qtableview, which is more suitable for this job ?
2. the second question is : how to draw a progress bar in the downloading task list ?
   P.S. if chosing Qtablewidget ,I know it has a 
   QTableWidget.setCellWidget(row, column, widget)

method ,so we can use it to set QprogressBar there .
if chosing Qtableview, we can use Delegate like here

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html

(maybe QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 will be more appropriate for the current Qt )

the same question comes here again :which way is more appropriate to do this ?

can anyone give a little example ? cuz the the Qt Torrent Example is so complicated for a newbie like me to learn from it .thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

Up to me it's very interesting discussion topic. If you look carefully in the documentation you will see that QTableWidget is actually a QTableView with specialised table-oriented functions, default table model, support for widgets in cells out of the box etc. It still has everything which QTableView has if you need some low level customisation. So you really don't have to choose. If you think (and looking on screenshots examples I would agree with that) that QTableWidget can handle most of things you need (like progress bars etc) just take it and go ahead with setCellWidget(...). Since it's QTableView anyway you always have an option to substitute it with your own QTableView implementation with fancy delegates etc. 
I think in your scenario you you will use very limited amount of QTableWidget specialised functions, so that shouldn't be any problems at all.

Making it short, on your place I would go for QTableWidget.

Comment: You can even use a custom delegate with a  `QTableWidget` using the `setItemDelegateForColumn` method.